# How to convert gchar* to char

Tags: c, netbeans, char, gtk, key-events

When I press a key(integer) on my keyboard. It does something like:

```
 gchar *keypressed;
 keypressed=gdk_keyval_name (event->keyval);
 printf("The KeyEvent is: %s\n", keypressed); // Till here it is fine
```

I get segmentation fault when I do this:

```
char ch;
sprintf(ch, "%s\n", keypressed);   
printf("The NewKeyEvent is: %s\n",ch);
```

I need to *convert* it as I am going to use the value in a *switch case*. Without converting it is not possible.

Comment: Your variable `ch` is a *single character*, it can't contain a string or be used as a string. Maybe you want an *array* of characters (e.g. `char str[32];`)?

Comment: Can you show me? Whatever it may be, I need the value stored on **keypressed** should be able to use in a switch case.

Comment: @djgharphalia07  then use a single char . But here `keypressed` has what length ?

Comment: @ameyCU at present **keypressed** may be a single integer number from 1-9.

Comment: @user3121023 It will be same using instead of **keypressed**? isn't it?

Comment: lets see then. I thought it will a char so cant be used in a switch :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89448/discussion-between-djgharphalia07-and-user3121023).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gchar` is a `typedef` alias of `char`, so the problem is not with the type conversion. You need to allocate some space for the `sprintf` buffer.

Currently, you are passing a single uninitialized `char` to where a pointer should be. You should get a warning from the compiler, in addition to a segfault caused by undefined behavior.

To fix this, make an array of `char`s and pass it to `sprintf` instead:

```
char ch[10];
sprintf(ch, "%8s\n", keypressed);   
printf("The NewKeyEvent is: %s\n", c);
```

Note the limit of 8 in the `sprintf`. This is because `ch` is of size 10, and we need two extra spots for `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: "I need to convert the it as I am going to use the value in a switch case. Without converting it is not possible." This wouldn't help you with the switch, though, because you cannot switch on a C string. You should switch on `event->keyval` itself, which has an integral type, and can be used as a `switch` expression.

Comment: I have converted using *atoi* and it is working fine now... event->keyval will be used soon :)

Comment: When I do press 2 from the keyboard above the letters. The event->keyval *takes*  it as a char value of decimel number 50. What should I do?

Comment: @djgharphalia07 Isn't that what it supposed to do? Decimal number 50 corresponds to character `'2'` in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: Yes! I know. I mean to say if I use *event->keyval* . Here too I have to convert the values. isn't it? So same thing.

Comment: @djgharphalia07 That depends on what you wish to do with it. If you write `switch(event->keyval) { case '0': ... break; case '1': ... break; case '2': ... break; ... default: }` (note the single quotes around digits) you would switch on the numeric value of the digit, not on its code.

Comment: I faced errors when I tried this the 1st time infact :(

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a single character from the `keypressed` string there are two ways:

1. Use array indexing, this way you can access any character in the string:

   ```
   char ch = keypressed[x];  // Where `x` is the character number you want
   ```

   <sub>Remember that array indexing starts from zero, so the first character in the string is number `0`.</sub>
2. If you want the first character, you can also use the dereference operator

   ```
   char ch = *keypressed;
   ```

   This equivalent to

   ```
   char ch = keypressed[0];
   ```